# how to calculate two numbers in a listbox

Tags: c#

I need to find a code so that I can subtract the biggest number from the lowest number in a list box. I added the list box items from the properties if anyone knows anything please help me I tried this code

```
  int lowestattendance = attenadances.Max();
  string lowestname = "";
  int index = 0;

   while (index < attenadances.Count) ;
   {
       if (attenadances[index] < lowestattendance)
       {
           lowestattendance = attenadances[index];
           lowestname = Names[index];
       }

       index++;
   }

   string message = string.Format(
     "the person with the lowest attendance is {0}" + "and his attendance is { 1}", 
      lowestname, 
      lowestattendance);

   MessageBox.Show(message, " lowest attendance");
```

and it never  showed anything.

Comment: Did you debug your code to see what was happening? When you say "it never showed anything," do you mean the messagebox didn't appear or that it didn't display the message you thought?

Comment: what is `attenadances`? Is it the name of the list box control?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `ArgMin` function; even if *Linq* doesn't have such thing, you can easily implement it with a help of `Aggregate`:

```
   using System.Linq;

   ...

   //TODO: typo - attendances, not attenadances 
   var lowest = attenadances
     .Select((value, index) => new {
        attendance = value,
        name = Names[index], })  
     .Aggregate((s, a) => s.attendance < a.attendance ? s : a);

   //DONE: { 1} should be {1}
   //DONE: can a woman be the top truant? - his/her 
   string message = string.Format(
     "the person with the lowest attendance is {0} and his/her attendance is {1}", 
      lowest.name, 
      lowest.attendance);

   //DONE: leading space eliminated
   MessageBox.Show(message, "lowest attendance");
```

If you don't want *Linq* but *loop* implemantation, I suggest using `for` isntead of `while`:

```
  int lowestattendance = 0;
  string lowestname = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < Attenadances.Count; ++i) 
    // change min: on the very 1st item; if next item is less than current min
    if (i == 0 || attenadances[i] < lowestattendance) {
      lowestattendance = attenadances[i];
      lowestname = Names[i]; 
    } 

  string message = string.Format(
    "the person with the lowest attendance is {0} and his/her attendance is {1}", 
     lowestname, 
     lowestattendance);

  MessageBox.Show(message, "lowest attendance");
```

Comment: Really nice answer :D, though I think it might be a little advanced considering the nature of the issue, and the experience of the developer (as far as I can tell from this question)

Comment: @Alfie Goodacre: I personally prefer *Linq* for it's readability (that's why I've started with it: if I had to find out the top truant I would do it like this). However, I agree that *Linq* can well be *difficult to understand* for newbie developers and so I've provide good old `for` loop implementation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you posted, you get a `FormatException` when you format your message. The reason is your placeholder `{ 1}` where the leading space is not allowed.

So replace your formatting code line

```
string message = string.Format(
    "the person with the lowest attendance is {0}" +
    "and his attendance is {1}", // change here from { 1} to {1}
    lowestname, lowestattendance);
```

If you have other issues, please be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` would work much better as a `for` loop, like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < attenadances.Count; i++)
    {
        if (attenadances[i] < lowestattendance)
        {
            lowestattendance = attenadances[i];
            lowestname = Names[i];
        }

    }
```

Notice how I also removed the semicolon?

`while (index < attenadances.Count) ;` turns into `for (int i = 0; i < attenadances.Count; i++)`

This is because the excess semicolon counts as your loop ending, so the computer is seeing

`WHILE index IS LESS THAN attendances.Count DO NOTHING`. As such it goes on doing nothing forever!